# Perf shows userspace cycles for cores which shouldn't be executing instructions

Tags: c++, linux, optimization, x86, perf

I have a test application like this:

```
int main()
{
    // calls sched_setaffinity() to set affinity to core 0

    while(true)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have 4x logical cores across 2x physical cores.

I would like to see perf event counters but only for the CPU core my app uses.

I run this Perf command (killing it after a few seconds):

```
sudo perf stat -e cycles:u --cpu=0 --delay=1000 ./app
```

four times, each time changing the cpu id, it shows `cycles:u` > 0.

How can all four cpus be executing userspace cycles for an application which pins to core 0?

Surely three of the cores should not be executing userspace cycles for my application?

Comment: How many cycles?  Have you tried `taskset -c 1 perf stat --all-user --cpu=0 ./app` to set CPU affinity *before* the process starts?  What CPU model?  Are there any errata related to the hardware event `perf` is using?  (But counts from a different physical core aren't plausible, that could only maybe explain failing to ignore counts for the other logical core sharing a physical.)

Comment: @PeterCordes okay so I removed the affinity code then ran `taskset -c 0 perf stat --all-user --cpu=0 ./app` (and changing `--cpu=`) all four commands show several billion for `instructions:uhH`. I presume this should be zero for 3 of them? CPU is an old Ivy Bridge.

Comment: This infinite loop is *undefined behaviour* (UB) in C++ (not in C). So an optimizing compiler can simply remove it or generate a wrong code. Mainstream compilers actually do that (e.g. Clang does it).

Comment: @JérômeRichard The loop is executing though, so Perf should still only show counters for one cpu because of `taskset`?

Comment: I guess this is certainly because you did not enabled optimization or you do not use Clang but a less optimizing compiler in this case. Relying on UB is dangerous. Even for basic benchmarks.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in WSL. The number of cycle is pretty small compared to the CPU frequency. Since perf is a sampling based profiler, it might be normal. If I attach perf to the pid of the target application, the number of cycle seems completely wrong : it is the same for all cores... I just tested with a (sequential) Python process run with `taskset -c 3 python -c "159482637**123456789"`. `htop` and `hwloc-ps` confirm Python is only running on the PU 3. I am not sure the perf implementation of WSL is comparable to the bare metal one though. I might be a bug...

Comment: @JérômeRichard this was just a quick hack test. what I'm trying to achieve is a really simple test to see how much time my application gets stopped because of scheduling or interrupts. Now I think about it, I don't think Perf can even show hardware interrupts? Could I do something like total cycles - user cycles = interrupted cycles?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I should simplify my previous comment. What's the simplest way in perf to measure how much time my app/thread spends not executing because the kernel decided to do something else, including hardware interrupts? Would `cycles:k` cover this?

Comment: @JérômeRichard: `perf stat` doesn't take "samples", it just counts.  It puts the HW counters into a different mode than `perf record`, or it just sets their wrap-around limit as high as possible so it only gets an interrupt on overflow.  Subtracting the start vs. end count values + limit x times-wrapped gives a precise count.  For events like user-space instructions retired, these are precise +- a couple counts if you profile a short static executable with a known number of instructions before an `exit` syscall, with the offset probably coming during the transition back to kernel mode

Comment: @intrigued_66: If your microbenchmark doesn't make any system calls, then yes, `cycles:k` would be a useful event to count.

Comment: @PeterCordes No system calls. I'm literally just spinning, nothing else. What are your thoughts regarding getting `perf` results for cpu cores my application is not `taskset` to?

Comment: I think it sounds weird, and am still waiting to hear what hardware and how many counts you're getting.  Like is it a couple counts, or some large fraction of the counts you get on the main core.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's an old i5-3320M. Regarding `cycles:k` values, with the process running for a few seconds, the taskset cpu returns a few billion cycles. The other 3 cpus return between 20 and 60 million cycles.

Comment: @PeterCordes so the other cpus are quieter, but why is the app executing 30 million cycles in the kernel when it's taskset to a different cpu?

Comment: Consider using `perf sched` to see what is interrupting the target process? Could be interrupts, scheduling... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the docs for `perf stat --cpu=` are wrong or misleading when they say *The `-a` option is still necessary to activate system-wide monitoring.*

It seems to behave identically with or without `-a`, so the counts are from other processes, like GUI animations, cursor blink, etc.  Or for `cycles:k`, from any interrupt handler regardless of which process is the kernel's `current` on that core.

---

I tested this on Arch GNU/Linux system with kernel and perf 6.5.  The smoking gun here is running another infinite-loop process pinned to a different core, and seeing `cycles:u` on that core the same as the core running the command from the perf command-line.

Baseline *without* any funky options, with `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'` as the command being profiled.  (It keeps a CPU core busy for a few seconds, making no system calls except at start and exit, and having a small cache footprint.)

```
$ taskset -c 1 perf stat -e task-clock,cycles:u  --delay=1000   awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
Events disabled
Events enabled

 Performance counter stats for 'awk BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}':

          2,625.29 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
    10,226,974,370      cycles:u                                                              

       2.625290561 seconds time elapsed
```

vs. with `--cpu`, two signs of not limiting itself to the `awk` process: task-clock is 8x longer than the elapsed time.  And the header it prints: *Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 0-7':* rather than for our process.

```
taskset -c 1 perf stat -e task-clock,cycles:u --cpu=0-7  --delay=1000   awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
Events disabled
Events enabled

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 0-7':

         23,621.12 msec task-clock                       #    8.000 CPUs utilized             
    12,747,549,694      cycles:u                                                              

       2.952544251 seconds time elapsed
```

And with `-A` aka `--no-aggr` to not aggregate across CPUs, each one has task-clock running for the full interval even though our process definitely isn't on it (since it and perf itself started pinned to CPU 1):

```
$ taskset -c 1 perf stat -e task-clock,cycles:u --cpu=0-7 -A  --delay=1000   awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
Events disabled
Events enabled

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 0-7':

CPU0             2,605.76 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU1             2,605.75 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU2             2,605.76 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU3             2,605.75 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU4             2,605.78 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU5             2,605.78 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU6             2,605.78 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU7             2,605.78 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU0          162,311,044      cycles:u                                                              
CPU1       10,153,813,410      cycles:u                                                              
CPU2           12,114,460      cycles:u                                                              
CPU3           49,619,566      cycles:u                                                              
CPU4          180,412,777      cycles:u                                                              
CPU5           51,045,799      cycles:u                                                              
CPU6          132,275,644      cycles:u                                                              
CPU7          344,942,273      cycles:u                                                              

       2.605703012 seconds time elapsed
```

And with a dummy load (like another awk process, or in this case I ran program that just loops on `pause` instruction, which isn't special other than using less power), we see it uses as many cycles core CPU 2 as `awk` did on CPU 1.

```
$ taskset -c 2 timeout 10m ~/src/SO/pauseloop &
    # actually on another terminal
$ taskset -c 1 perf stat -e task-clock,cycles:u --cpu=0-7 -A  --delay=1000   awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'
Events disabled
Events enabled

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 0-7':

CPU0             2,721.71 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU1             2,721.71 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU2             2,721.71 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU3             2,721.71 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU4             2,721.70 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU5             2,721.70 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU6             2,721.69 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU7             2,721.69 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized             
CPU0          861,492,255      cycles:u                                                              
CPU1       10,485,755,009      cycles:u                                                              
CPU2       10,485,655,861      cycles:u                                                              
CPU3          559,708,162      cycles:u                                                              
CPU4        1,207,134,025      cycles:u                                                              
CPU5          556,142,162      cycles:u                                                              
CPU6          623,020,558      cycles:u                                                              
CPU7        3,721,131,901      cycles:u                                                              

       2.721620976 seconds time elapsed
```

Note the `10,485,755,009` vs. `10,485,655,861` counts for `cycles:u` on cores 1 and 2. The same to within one part per 10k.  (At 3.9GHz on my i7-6700k, and the absolute difference is about 1 million, or about 250 nanoseconds, which could easily be accounted for by differences in starting / stopping counting on different cores.)

---

### `-a --cpu` only changes the header message, not counts

Adding `-a` to any of these (except the one without `--cpu`) changes nothing except the header message, to *Performance counter stats for 'system wide':* instead of *'CPU(s) 0-7'*

Everything I'm seeing is consistent with `--cpu` actually counting everything happening on that core wile `perf stat` is running, just like `-a` mode.

Comment: So there's no way of seeing metrics only for the CPU which matters? This seems a rather large bug!

Comment: @intrigued_66: `taskset -c 1 perf stat ./a.out` shows you counts for CPU 1 while `./a.out` is scheduled on it, the default behaviour for perf (pinning means we know what core it'll be). Including kernel counts from system calls an interrupt handlers.    You could do `-e cycles:u,cycles:k` to count them separately I guess.  `taskset -c 1 perf stat --cpu=1 ./a.out` shows you counts for anything on CPU 1 including other user-space tasks if there were any context-switches away from your process.  (Like for `perf` itself because I pinned it to the same core, you might want to avoid that.)

Comment: Further confirmation: `-A` without `--cpu=` is an error: `both cgroup and no-aggregation modes only available in system-wide mode`.

Comment: Okay so what we're saying is if you use `--cpu` it doesn't guarantee the results will be specific to that process? It just means perf will show you whatever is executing on that cpu for the duration that process is running. If you isolate that core and use it for your process, then the cpu will only execute that process (and kernel) but if you don't, the perf results will contain other processes?

Comment: @intrigued_66: Right.  Yeah, `--cpu` seems to imply `-a` for the set of cores you pick.  Without `-a` or `--cpu`, pinning your task to a specific CPU and using `perf` normally will let you see user and/or kernel counts (including interrupts) while it's the `current` task.  If no other tasks take a timeslice on that core, that will be the whole time, especially if it doesn't `sleep`.  (If the count for `context-switches` is zero, that means no other user-space tasks ran on that core.  I'm not 100% sure about kernel tasks like IRQ bottom halves or `khugepaged` etc.)